# What's the difference of the command output after inputting the command "env", "export", "set" under Bash Shell in Solaris?

Tags: bash, shell, export, solaris, env

OS: Solaris

Shell: Bash Shell

Scenario: Input the commands separately: "env", "export" and "set" (without any arguments) and there will be a list of variables and values returned.

My question: What's the difference among the returned values after inputting the three commands?

Comment: As a matter of idle curiosity, do you know which `bash` version you have on your Solaris machine?  I tried on a Solaris 9 box and got `GNU bash, version 2.05.0(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.9)`, which is rather older than I was expecting (but then again, Solaris 9 is not in its first flush of old age, let alone youth).

Comment: My version is `GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `env` and `export` commands yield the same information, but not in the same format.  And `bash`'s `export` produces a very radically different output from the output of `ksh` or (Bourne) shell's version.  Note that `set` and `export` are shell built-in commands, but `env` is an external command that has other uses than just listing the content of the environment (though that is one of its uses).

The `set` command lists the variables you've created.  This includes environment variables, regular (non-environment) variables, *and* function definitions (which we'll ignore here).

Consider:

```
x1=abc
x2=def; export x2
export x3=ghi
```

There are two exported variables (`x2` and `x3`), and one regular (non-exported) variable.  The `set` command will list all three; `export` and `env` will only list the exported ones.

The output of the [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) command is mandated by the POSIX standard.  This is simply the variable name and value followed by a newline:

```
name=value
```

Classically, the Bourne shell simply listed variables the same way for both `set` and `export`.

Korn shell encloses values in quotes if the value contains spaces or other characters that need protection, but otherwise uses the `name=value` notation.

The `set` command in `bash` generates assignments with the value protected in quotes.  However, the output for `export` is a `declare -x var=value` with quote protection.  The general idea is presumably that you can use `export > file` followed by `source file` to reset the environment variables to the values that were in the environment at the time you did the `export`.

---

#### Summary

1. Not all shell variables are environment variables.
2. The `set` command lists all shell variables and may list functions too.
3. The `export` command lists environment variables.
4. The `set` and `export` commands are built into the shell.
5. The `env` command with no arguments lists the environment it inherited from the process that executed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I have been clear about the difference

Answer (score 0):

The `set` command shows you all of the shell variables defined in your session.

The `export` command lists a subset (usually) of the ones above. These are created with either `export` or `declare -x` : variables which are globally visible - ie., visible to child processes.

The `env` command is used to to enable porting scripts from account to another account or machine to machine.
env runs a program in a modified or different environment.