# Unix user created variables

Tags: shell, variables, unix

I am going though some growing pains with Unix. My question:

I want to be able to print all my user defined variables in my shell.  Let say I do the following in the shell:

```
$ x=9
$ y="Help"
$ z=-18
$ R="My 4th variable"
```

How would I go about printing:

x y z R

Comment: Lots of into here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262292/whats-the-difference-of-the-command-output-after-inputting-the-command-env

Comment: you only add the dollar sign when reading the variable value, not when setting it.

Comment: Yes. Good call @mnagel.  I was trying to "emulate the shell" I suppose.  My instructor seems to do that in his notes and it just carried over to what I wrote.

Comment: If the `$` is supposed to represent your shell prompt (which is a common convention when showing interactive commands), put a space after it. I'll edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should record your variables first at runtime with `set`, then compare it later to see which variables were added. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set | grep -E '^[^[:space:]]+=' | cut -f 1 -d = | sort > /tmp/previous.txt

a=1234
b=1234

set | grep -E '^[^[:space:]]+=' | cut -f 1 -d = | sort > /tmp/now.txt

comm -13 /tmp/previous.txt /tmp/now.txt
```

Output:

```
a
b
PIPESTATUS
```

Notice that there are still other variables produced by the shell but is not declared by the user. You can filter them with `grep -v`. It depends on the shell as well.

Add: Grep and cut could simply be just one sed a well: `sed -n 's/^\([^[:space:]]\+\)=.*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 3):

Type `set`:

```
$ set
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-jiNTOC/Render
BASH=/bin/bash
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="51" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-apple-darwin13")
BASH_VERSION='3.2.51(1)-release'
COCOS2DROOT=/Users/andy/Source/cocos2d
COLUMNS=80
DIRSTACK=()
...
```

(Oh, and BTW, you appear to have your variable syntax incorrect as you assign, say, `A` but print `$A`)

Answer (score 0):

If variables are exported then you can use `env` command in Unix.

Comment: only if the variables are exported.